# Inserting image in an attribute table in QGIS Composer?

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I'm trying to create second page of map atlas. In this page I need to show all records in the range of current atlas page.

I've used Insert Attribute Table tool in composer and it worked. But I need to add a graphic to every record (on the end on attribute table).

Is there a possibility to show image from attribute table in composer or I need to use some separate HTML code?

Answer (score 2):

It's not currently possible. You may be able to achieve this using a html item with dynamic html, but it's still going to be tricky. You'd either need to prefill an attribute in your table with the html table content, or take advantage of a query which does this on the fly if you're using a spatial database backend.